# Modifying sequence operations with external condition

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

Often I find myself working with some STL container and wishing to modify it based on some external condition. By external, I mean something that cannot be derived from the object in the container alone.

For example, let's say I have worked out which elements of the container I want to keep based on some elaborate criterion involving not only the elements themselves. The keep flags are stored in a container of the same size as the original container. Now I want to use std::remove_if to remove those for which the flag is zero. How can I do that?

```
std::vector<Foo> container_of_foos;
std::vector<int> to_keep(container_of_foos.size(), 0); 
// ... code calculates which foos to keep and stores a flag for each one
// NOTE: the condition relies information external to the Foo class (could be relation to other Foo instances)
auto i_new_end = std::remove_if(begin(container_of_foos), end(container_of_foos), [&to_keep](const Foo& foo) {
    // can't tell whether to keep, because I don't know which object is iterated now
});
```

Comment: This is straightforward if you have Boost or range-v3. Are you limited to using just the standard library?

Comment: @T.C. I am open to using boost as long as the programming overhead is reasonable. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

**Using `boost::zip_iterator`**

`boost::zip_iterator` over a set of tuple iterators really simplifies the removal.

```
std::vector<int> numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
std::vector<bool> selectors = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1};

auto zip_first = boost::make_zip_iterator(
    boost::make_tuple(selectors.begin(), numbers.begin()));
auto zip_last = zip_first + std::min(selectors.size(), numbers.size());

auto removed_first = std::remove_if(zip_first, zip_last, [](const auto& tup) {
  return boost::get<0>(tup) == 0;
});
```

[Live example on Wandbox.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Qg9Q2kutoLLn7Kza)

**Using algorithms (non-boost)**

Write your own `remove`/`remove_if` that takes two ranges (values and selectors) and a value/predicate.  You'll have to decide on how you want to handle mismatched range distances.  Once you have two ranges in your expected state, you can run compress both by erasing.  Below is an example of compressing a range that is filtered using another range, terminating on the shortest sequence.

**Remove by value and predicate**

```
template <typename FwdIt1, typename FwdIt2, typename ValueType>
auto remove(FwdIt1 first1, FwdIt1 last1, FwdIt2 first2, FwdIt2 last2,
            const ValueType value) {
  FwdIt1 curr1 = first1;
  FwdIt2 curr2 = first2;

  for (; curr1 != last1 && curr2 != last2; ++curr1, ++curr2) {
    if (value != *curr2) {
      *first1++ = std::move(*curr1);
      *first2++ = std::move(*curr2);
    }
  }
  return std::make_pair(first1, first2);
}

template <typename FwdIt1, typename FwdIt2, typename Predicate>
auto remove_if(FwdIt1 first1, FwdIt1 last1, FwdIt2 first2, FwdIt2 last2,
               Predicate pred) {
  FwdIt1 curr1 = first1;
  FwdIt2 curr2 = first2;

  for (; curr1 != last1 && curr2 != last2; ++curr1, ++curr2) {
    if (!pred(*curr2)) {
      *first1++ = std::move(*curr1);
      *first2++ = std::move(*curr2);
    }
  }
  return std::make_pair(first1, first2);
}
```

**Container-based Compression (remove & erase) helpers**

```
template <typename Container, typename Selector, typename ValueType>
auto compress(Container& values, Selector& selectors, const ValueType& value) {
  const auto remove_iters =
      remove(std::begin(values), std::end(values), std::begin(selectors),
             std::end(selectors), value);
  return std::make_pair(
      values.erase(remove_iters.first, std::end(values)),
      selectors.erase(remove_iters.second, std::end(selectors)));
}

template <typename Container, typename Selector, typename Predicate>
auto compress_if(Container& values, Selector& selectors, Predicate pred) {
  const auto remove_iters =
      remove_if(std::begin(values), std::end(values), std::begin(selectors),
                std::end(selectors), pred);
  return std::make_pair(
      values.erase(remove_iters.first, std::end(values)),
      selectors.erase(remove_iters.second, std::end(selectors)));
}
```

[Live Example on Wandbox.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sVGv4qy4ArZoU5qT)

Comment: 1) you can use `boost::range::combine` with `boost::range::remove_if` to simplify the Boost case. 2) Using `zip_iterator` causes `remove_if` to do copy assignments rather than move assignments, which may be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, use a lambda as the predicate.  For example;

```
void func()
{
     std::vector<int> container;

      // populate container
     int flag = 42;

      //  modify flag as needed

      auto lambda = [flag](int element) {return element < flag;}  // whatever

     std::remove_if(container.begin(), container.end(), lambda);
}
```

Before C++11, use a functor.

```
struct remover
{
     int flag;
     remover(int flag_value) : flag(flag_value) {};

     bool operator()(int element) {return element < flag;};
};

void func()
{
     std::vector<int> container;

      // populate container
     int flag = 42;

      //  modify flag as needed


     remover functor(flag);

     std::remove_if(container.begin(), container.end(), functor);
}
```

These two samples are essentially equivalent.

In C++11, look up lambda capture specifications to work out how to pass other variables to the lambda.   Before that, change the functor so it is constructed using whatever variables are needed.

Comment: this does not work when the flag is itself a container of the same size, because you don't know which index to access while in the lambda expression

Answer (score 0):

`&x-vec.data()` is the index of `x` in `vec`.

Assuming, of course, that `x` is in `vec`: otherwise, is UB.

Comment: yes, more generally using std::distance, but this is reverting to using standard indexed loops, which I am looking for a way to avoid

Comment: @killo the remove if remains: we just dobthebother lookup via index.  Distance is not O(1) in all cases: the above is.  *and* you need iterators for distance: the above requires a reference, not an iterator.  Using distance hides what is going on, it does not clarify.